# How to propagate ExcludeView/IncludeView in natvis?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, natvis

So, say I have 2 classes, C and B where they have a composition relationship, C is composed of B.

```c++
struct C
{
};

struct B
{
  C c;
};
```

Now, I have a natvis file that has 2 views of C.  Must I explicitly propagate this view from B to C?  This sounds like a lot of hassle since the natvis file doesn't state the types that are being displayed resulting in missing locations where I want that view propagated.  Also, this wouldn't work for containers.  I would only have a view for an individual item.

**EDIT:**

Example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010">
  <Type Name="C">
    <DisplayString>View 1</DisplayString>
  </Type>

  <Type Name="C" IncludeView="two">
    <DisplayString>View 2</DisplayString>
  </Type>

  <Type Name="B">
    <DisplayString>B</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
      <Item Name="C">c</Item>
    </Expand>
  </Type>
</AutoVisualizer>
```

Now in the watch window I look at a variable `b` which is of type `B`.  To see it, I type:

```
b, view(two)
```

To which I would expect the view to propagate to the view of `c`.  But it doesn't.  It would instead show:

```
c    View 1
```

Without having to write:

```xml
  <Type Name="B">
    <DisplayString>B</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
      <Item Name="C" ExcludeView="two">c</Item>
      <Item Name="C" IncludeView="two">c</Item>
    </Expand>
  </Type>
```

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: what do you mean by "propagate"? between different .natvis files?

Comment: @liorda, updated question to answer yours.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't pass the view type to nested elements. Even for your example

```xml
  <Type Name="B">
    <DisplayString>B</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
      <Item Name="C1" ExcludeView="two">c</Item>
      <Item Name="C2" IncludeView="two">c</Item>
    </Expand>
  </Type>
```

it doesn't work as expected:

[image: example]

You have to add `, view(two)` to get right view:

```
  <Type Name="B">
    <DisplayString>B</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
      <Item Name="C1" ExcludeView="two">c</Item>
      <Item Name="C2" IncludeView="two">c, view(two)</Item>
    </Expand>
  </Type>
```

[image: tested on MSVS 2019]